# AWS SES set up in a different region than the domain/EC2...email failure to verify after domain is verified

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I have had an EC2 server set up for a while in the Ohio region. Later, I went to set up email for it, and SES is not available for that region. So I fired up another server in N. Virginia, where SES is available. I go into SES, enter my domain (of the original EC2 over in Ohio), and verify it.

The verification of the domain worked, but now I cannot verify an email address, and I cannot receive email at that domain (I'm trying to dump it into an S3 bucket, if that matters). Is this impossible, to have SES trying to deal with email in another region from the original EC2? What would be the best solution for this situation here?

Any help is appreciated. I'm pretty new AWS in general, and still trying to figure out a lot of how it works.

UPDATE: Several days later, the email address has failed the verification. So as of right now, the domain is verified and enabled for sending, but an email address at that domain is failed. How does that happen, and what can I do?

Comment: It should work fine. Please detail the errors or issues you are encountering.

Comment: I cannot verify an email address at that domain (it's just stuck pending), and I am not receiving any email in my S3 bucket. I thought it was a region issue, but maybe not. What else should I be checking? I'm not encrypting so I didn't think I needed to adjust S3 permissions, but what do you think?

Comment: The email delivery is not immediate, it may take an hour. Did your pending status span more than one hour ? I also remember long time ago I had an instance in Oregon and the email SES in VIrginia and it was working. But, what does it mean that you want to "dump" the email in S3 ?

Comment: Yeah, the email has been pending for 24 hours now, and when I've tried to email the address from a different email account, it returned Mail Delivery System error, so I'm fairly certain it is not working.

Comment: I'm confirming that the region does not matter, but email verification is not done right away. You should wait about a day or two for it to work. You don't need an EC2 instance in that region for SES to work.

Comment: As for S3, I was told I had to set up an active Rule Set to tell SES what to do with the emails that arrive. I chose that all incoming emails would be put into an S3 bucket. There is nothing in that bucket except for the automated "Amazon SES setup notification". But that is where the emails should reside, if they were getting through. Now that I'm explaining it all, the issue is probably the permissions in S3, even though I was so convinced it was because of the regional differences!

Comment: Thanks to both Mark and Radu for confirmation that it was not a regional problem. I suppose those comments answer this specific overflow question.